# Application error when calling python function

Tags: python, twilio, airtable

I am building a voicemail application that recieves phone calls via Twilio, takes a message, and then records the information in an Airtable database. I have everything working fine but it is a lot of repeated code so I wanted to consolidate it but I'm running into errors when calling the function.

Here is what I have now...

```
@app.route("/call", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def caller():

    phone = request.values.get('From', None)
    campaign = request.values.get('To')

    if campaign == brand_1.phone:
        brand = brand_1
        resp = VoiceResponse()
        resp.play(brand.recording)
        resp.record(maxLength="30")
        recording_url = request.values.get("RecordingUrl", None)
        brand.at.create('Leads', data = {'Phone':phone,'Campaign':campaign, 'Voicemail':recording_url})
        return str(resp)
    elif campaign == brand_2.phone:
        brand = brand_2
        resp = VoiceResponse()
        resp.play(brand.recording)
        resp.record(maxLength="30")
        recording_url = request.values.get("RecordingUrl", None)
        brand.at.create('Leads', data = {'Phone':phone,'Campaign':campaign, 'Voicemail':recording_url})
        return str(resp)
    elif campaign == brand_3.phone:
        brand = brand_3
        resp = VoiceResponse()
        resp.play(brand.recording)
        resp.record(maxLength="30")
        recording_url = request.values.get("RecordingUrl", None)
        brand.at.create('Leads', data = {'Phone':phone,'Campaign':campaign, 'Voicemail':recording_url})
        return str(resp)
    return "Success!"
```

As you can see, I'm repeating the same code three times. It works, but it's ugly and takes up space so I wanted to create a separate function that looks like this...

```
def voicemail(brand, phone, campaign):
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.play(brand.recording)
    resp.record(maxLength="30")
    recording_url = request.values.get("RecordingUrl", None)
    brand.at.create('Leads', data = {'Phone':phone,'Campaign':campaign, 'Voicemail':recording_url})
    return str(resp)
```

So I'd like to have look like this...

```
@app.route("/call", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def caller():

    phone = request.values.get('From', None)
    campaign = request.values.get('To')

    if campaign == brand_1.phone:
        brand = brand_1
        voicemail(brand, phone, campaign)
    elif campaign == brand_2.phone:
        brand = brand_2
        voicemail(brand, phone, campaign)
    elif campaign == brand_3.phone:
        brand = brand_3
        voicemail(brand, phone, campaign)
    return "Success!"
```

It seems like this should work but it doesn't. Twilio just says "An application error has occurred"

What am I missing here guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second pattern makes the function `caller()` only returns the final "Success".
You should try :

```
return voicemail(brand, phone, campaign)
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!